# iOS: Крэш приложения через несколько дней не использования

Tags: ios, swift

Прошу простить если вопрос глупый - только разбираюсь со Swift)

Делаю приложение, оно без проблем работает как на симуляторе, так и на реальном устройстве. Но если приложение несколько дней не запускать, то при старте оно сразу же вылетает. В консоли всего две строчки:

```
Dec  1 10:32:19 MacBook-Pro testApp[52480]: assertion failed: 19A602 17A844: libxpc.dylib + 83383 [F391B106-5033-3156-98D9-705C5A7FDECD]: 0x7d
Dec  1 10:32:22 MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.CBE11191-44EF-40FD-A54C-B3E15AD60673[52124] (UIKitApplication:abp.testApp[cecc][rb-legacy][52480]): Service exited due to SIGILL | sent by exc handler[52480]
```

Если переустановить - все снова работает. Несколько дней не трогаешь, запускаешь - вылет.

Куда копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это потому что вы не приобрели аккаунт разработчика (который за $99). Пока не купите, придётся так периодически билдить, если не ошибаюсь через каждые 5 дней.

Comment: Спасибо, об этом я не подумал)

Comment: Я свое первое приложение больше полгода так писал :)